# Can I use Unity in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, unity-game-engine, air

I know Unity does not support Flash anymore. Recently I've been trying to bring Unity in Flash. But I'm stuck now. So I would like to ask about if it can be done.

Development environment:

Tool: Flash CC

Language: ActionScript 3.0

SDK: Adobe AIR 17

Platform: Windows OS

Comment: No, You cannot use Unity3D inside an .swf.

Comment: Why would you actually want to do so? Maybe there is an alternative...

Comment: Maybe describe what you are trying to do instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use Unity3D inside of Flash.

Comment: It's just impossible. Unity3D and its runtime are just outside of the scope of Flash. Maybe replacing Flash with Unity3D is the step you need to take.

Comment: Thanks you Code Clown!